# Allow extra elements in GitLab MD wiki

Tags: svg, markdown, gitlab

I have a GitLab server, on which various projects are hosted. I want to allow users to embed SVG directly into their wikis using the `<SVG>` tag. However, they seem to be filtered and do not show up once added to the wiki.

I've found some docs saying that this is because Ruby on Rails has a configurable whitelist of tags. I've looked for 2 configuration files but the ones I could find, and edited, didn't make a difference. Also ran a gitlab-ctl reconfigure to be sure.

Does anyone know how to get `<SVG>` tags working in the gitlab wikis?

Answer (score 1):

Within Markdown you can simply use:

```
![1](https://URL.svg)
```

to render SVG inline. You have an [example here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/16480).

Currently is not possible to render `<svg>` tags within markdown.

See the documentation for `HTML::Pipeline::SanitizationFilter` class for the list of allowed HTML tags and attributes: [SanitizationFilter Whitelist](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#WHITELIST-constant).

In addition to the default `SanitizationFilter` whitelist, GitLab also permits the usage of `<span>` elements.

Comment: Yea we're already using this way of embedding, but we would prefer to be able to have the entire SVG defined inline.. I've tried to customize the whitelist to allow SVG directly by editting the appropriate ruby config files, but it didn't make a difference. Thanks for the relevant info though, it's good to have this answer on stackoverflow as well.